# There is a conflict between Jdeveloper and MAF in JAVA version,how can I solve this?

Tags: macos, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I'm using the JDeveloper to developer MAF on mac , but when I install the Jdeveloper , it shows warning it don't support JDK Version(Java 1.8.0_40),it only support the Java version 7.0 - 8.0 .But Official tutorial says the MAF 2.2.1 needs Java 8.0 to deploy iOS8.1.

So there is conflict in Java version , I tried to use both JAVA version(8.0 and 7.2),it can open the Jdeveloper , but both have something error in software .

How can I solve this problem , THX~

Answer (score 1):

First install JDK 7.
Then using that version install JDev 12.1.3.
Next install JDK 8.
Download and install the MAF extension.
JDeveloper will prompt you to point to the JDK 8 location.
Done.

Next MAF version is going to work on JDev 12.2.1 which uses JDK 8 already.

Comment: Hi, I have tried  , but it seems have some conflicts(I thought it's Xcode version problem,so I update my Xcode version)  then I delete all my file and install another time , but this time after I install the MAF(which tried both local file & download) and didn't get the hint to locate JDK , and I can't find the MAF Option when I create a new Application.. It seems I didn't install the MAF..Do you have any idea the problem is?

Comment: I check all the inventory , didn't find any directory contain system12.1.3 , there is only two system directory . The one is webcenter->modules->com.bea.wsrp_10.3.2.0->system( contains a bunch of .jar files). the other one is in wenapp->portalConfig->jms->modules->system (which contain JMSSystemmodules.book). Can you show me more details? THX

Comment: I follow this tutorial find the file https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2011/08/13/how-to-find-and-reset-the-system11-x-x-x-folder-for-a-jdeveloper-installation/   Thx for your help . and sorry for the my poor reputation couldn't give you a upvote~~